# Modifying JMeter dashboard generation

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am executing JMeter test script using the command line. So JMeter has provided a command that generates dashboard using log.jtl file.

```
jmeter -g %JTLLOGPATH% -o %DASHBOARDPATH%
```

In the dashboard, There is some APDEX (Application Performance Index) table, statistics table, and graphs.
is there any setting or properties so that table in the dashboard will show required column and enable/disable graphs?

Comment: any feedback on answer ?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter Dashboard was changed, Latest version 3.3 allow you to [configure](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration) report generator using property file:

> All report generator properties can be found in file reportgenerator.properties. To customize these properties, you should copy them in user.properties file and modify them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such possibility as of Apache JMeter 3.0

But you can submit an enhancement request giving more details on your need.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html